# Cannot authenticate session - laravel 4.2

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

```
if(Auth::attempt(['username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')])){
    return Auth::user();
}
return 'Failed!';
```

That is the problematic code and I am sure the problem is in the `Auth::attempt` line. I have found other topics about this, but neither of them had a solution. I.e.: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1314-laravel-from-scratch-authentication-lesson-help/0

My `User` model implements the `UserInterface` and I have also put `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth as Auth;` in the controller, in case it is not recognized in the `Auth::attempt` part. Nevertheless, it doesn't work both with and without the `use ...`.

I tried also with

```
Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password'))
```

And I always get to the `Failed!` part...

The password is stored as hashed string in the DB, and when I debug with the following:

```
echo Input::get('username') . "____" . Input::get('password');
die();
```

I get the correct results. So, I can't think of anything else than that the problem must occur in the `::attempt` function.

Any sussgestions?

**Update: ** The `User` model

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'email'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'email'    => 'required'
    ];

    public static $error_messages;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public static function isValid($input)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($input, static::$rules);
        if ($validation->passes()) return true;

        static::$error_messages = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your `User` model?

Comment: @lukasgeiter - I found the problem and posted an answer. Thank you, though, for the try.

Comment: Great! Would have taken me pretty long time to guess that one. I'll add it to the list in my mind for the next "auth is not working" question here on SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem:

Interesting enough, it was in the DB. The `password` column had a limit of 15 characters, whereas the hash coded password value has tens of characters. Therefore the hashing of password value, taken from the input, was not fully saved in the DB, but instead just the first 15 chars of the hash code. And, therefore, the de-hashing (if I can call it like that) was never successful. :)

This is a very foolish mistake, but very easy to stumble upon, in my opinion...

Comment: By the way: "Please remember when building the Schema for this Model to ensure that the password field is a **minimum of 60 characters**.", [Official Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#configuration)

Comment: I am learning just from Laracasts' video tuts and troubleshooting+research online. I guess I have to read the official docs as well... :)

Comment: It doesn't hurt to ;)